# Passing a parameter to SQL Server query using read_sql_query

Tags: python

I have a one column list of Member_IDs called Member_ID_only2 similar to below:
Member ID
'123',
'456',
'758',
.
.
.
 I'm trying to pass this as a list parms to a read_sql_query.  My code sample is below:

'''
'''
import pandas as pd 
import pyodbc

```
conn = pyodbc.connect()
query = open(path + 'XXXXX_PROD.SQL', 'r')
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=(Member_ID_only2,))
My XXXXX_PROD.SQL has a where statement below:
WHERE MEME_CK IN '%s'
```

'''
I'm getting the error below:
'''
    DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '<_io.TextIOWrapper 
    name='C:\Folder\XXXXX_PROD.SQL' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>': The first argument 
 '''   to execute must be a string or unicode query.

I'm not sure how to fix it.  Can someone help?
Thank you for any help that I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open method opens the file and returns a TextIOWrapper object but does not read the content of the files.

To actually get the content of the file, you need to call the read method on that object, like so:

```
# Read the sql file
query = open('filename.sql', 'r')

DF = pd.read_sql_query(query.read(),connection,your_params)
```

By the aid of **with open** you will be ensure the file is properly closed
    with open(filename.sql', 'r') as query:
        DF = pd.read_sql_query(query.read(),connection,your_params)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  When I tried this snippet of code, i get the error below:

Comment: _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Comment: It is because you are using request, let me know how do you get Member_ID_only2, I assume you get it via request, I meant that convert it to encode('utf-8')

Comment: I have a one column list of Member_IDs with a field called Member ID  = '123', '456', '758', .etc..  So I'm trying these member Ids to my SQL query.

Comment: You just need to convert your column to utf, dateval = Member_ID_only2.encode('utf-8')

Comment: When I try to convert it, I get the error:  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'.

Comment: @Dsalcantara I changed my answer please try to read your query, you can not just open it and use it, you need to invoke read(). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that.  Just an FYI, I've only been programming in Python for a little while.

Comment: I finally got my SQL to work, although I had to change my statements.  What I got to work was below:

- For my Member list, I had to use the zip() to create an iterator of tuples = list_of_members_one_row and my SQL structure looks like below

SQL_Query = pd.read_sql(‘’’
Select …
From …
Where …
              AND MEME.Member_ID IN ('%s')
              ‘’’
% ("','".join(list_of_members_one_row)), conn)

SQL_output_pd = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query)

I really appreciate your help!  Thank you.